# Unix - Change created folder name if it already exist

Tags: unix, terminal, mkdir

I have a script that creates a folder with `mkdir` command.
Any time I run this script I need it to sequence the name of the folder according to the existing folders. So -

1. if there is no folder with the base name it will be called `base`
2. The next run will create `base1` etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the way, not an expert in Unix so I would appreciate comments -

```
base="folder_name"
val=0

while [ -d "$base$val" ];
do
  val=`expr $val + 1`
done

if [($val != 0)]; 
then
base=$base$val
fi

mkdir $base
cd $base
```